# How to duplicate a table in the same database and preserve the original ID in t sql

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, duplicates

I need to make a copy of TableA and name it TableB in the same Database and I did this :

```
SELECT * INTO TableB FROM TableA
```

But all IDs autoincrement also in the TableB and don't preserve the original one, so I got a copy of TableA but the IDs are different.

I want the IDs to be the same as the TableA, since I want a copy.

That seems maybe easy, but I'm kinda new to this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to preserve IDs and doesn't want database to auto increment the ID values, you can set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to ON , so that ID value can be specified during insertion and it will be preserved.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB ON

SELECT * INTO TableB FROM TableA 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to turn on identity insert to allow custom IDs to be inserted into the new table

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table { ON | OFF }

E.G. SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB ON
```

See the following MSDN article for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Just be sure to also set it back to off when you are done as it's not good to leave it on.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted =)